# Jquery get selected option's value and custom attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var x = document.getElementById("selectCity"); 
var options = ["Bangalore", "Pune", "Kolkata"]; 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    element.textContent = opt;
    element.value = opt;
    x.appendChild(element);
}

$('select[name="cityDropdown"]').change(function(){
  cityName=$(this).val();
 });
```

Now with each city i want to store my circle name. and save it as an attribute and pass when the city is selected

Comment: i want to hardcode to a list of circle & city like

1.Lucknow UP 2. patna : bihar jharkhand 3. chdigard : punjab
city name should be displayed in dropdown and when i select and proceed my cityname as well as circle name should be passed

Answer (score 1):

You can Hardcode a custom attribute to a `select`'s option. For example,

```
<option circle="UP" value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
```

and get it's value with jquery like this,

```
var circle = $('option:selected', this).attr("circle");
```

**HTML**

```
<select name="cityDropdown">
  <option circle="UP" value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
  <option circle="Bihar" value="Patana">Patana</option>
  <option circle="Punjab" value="Chandigarh">Chandigarh</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('select[name="cityDropdown"]').change(function(){
    var cityName = $(this).val();
    var circle = $('option:selected', this).attr("circle");
    console.log(cityName + " : " + circle);
});
```

Note : You can also use other custom attribute (custom attribute **city** for example). But you just need to use city as `value` of the option.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chto5pev/8/).

Answer (score 0):

make a proper selector ..try this ..

```
 $('#selectCity').change(function(){
       cityName = $(this).val(); 
       console.log(cityName); // do something
     });
```

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/de4dt8xc/) is the fiddle..

Comment: no my question is how do i make my city list a 2d array  so that i save city as well as circle. and in my dripdown it gets called as                        <option circle="CircleName" city="cityName">cityName</option>

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("selectCity"); 
var options = ["Bangalore", "Pune", "Kolkata"]; 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    element.textContent = opt;
    element.value = opt;
    element.setAttribute('circle-name', 'your value'); // your attribute
    x.appendChild(element);
}

$('select[name="cityDropdown"]').change(function(){
  cityName=$(this).val();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var optionAttr = $('#cityDropdown option:selected').attr("circle");
var optionAttr1 = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("circle");
```

Comment: Why suddenly use `$(this)`?

Comment: You answer could be improved by including a description of your code so that others can understand what it does and how it addresses the question.